# Reading & writing variable length byte[] to file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am developing a Java application that reads and writes byte arrays (of seemingly random bytes) in a file.

I would like to know what method I can use to separate these byte arrays, because if I encode them in UTF-8, I might run into a newline character by accident right?

So then the `bufferedReader.nextLine()` might think it's the end of a byte[]?

Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: If they're binary, you shouldn't be treating them as text.

Comment: if you aren't writing text data, don't use libraries meant for reading in text files.

Comment: Then how can I read and write the bytes?

Comment: Can you clarify what would be a "correct" separation into byte arrays?  It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to write byte arrays to a file. I have no idea where these begin or end, and they are not a fixed length. The only way I know to read a file is with a `BufferedReader`, and when it's reading a file with binary data in it, it might read a newline character and interpret it as the separation of 2 arrays. I think I'll prepend the length of the array in 2 bytes before the actual data starts.

Comment: OK, well any class with `Reader` in the name will convert bytes to characters, and therefore should NOT be used for reading binary data.  You might consider using `BufferedInputStream` instead of `BufferedReader`.  It's the binary equivalent.

Comment: I'm currently writing my code as follows: DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))); int length = ((byte) dis.read()) << 8 | ((byte) dis.read()); byte[] pubkey = new byte[length]; dis.read(pubkey); And writing similar with a DataOutputStream. This seems to work. Could you put your comment as a response? Maybe mention that I shouldn't treat byte arrays as text, and about using separate bytes to indicate length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing and reading bytes you probably just want to use a [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

The way you separate the different byte arrays is by knowing the number of bytes and the order they appear in the file.

Comment: So I have to store the length of the byte arrays?

Comment: Or somehow know that it's fixed width.  You could use the first couple of bytes (some fixed number) to tell you how long the given String is.  Check out netstrings:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring